# Making jump look realistic?

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

Here is my source code for the program. Skim it if necessary:

```
import pygame, sys
import time
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1500,750])
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill([255, 255, 255])

class Attacker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x_pos, self.y_pos = location
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = location
        self.jumping = False
        self.falling = False
        self.direction = 1


    def jump(self):
        if self.y_pos > CEILING:
            self.x_pos += 1*self.direction
            self.y_pos -= 5
        else:
            self.jumping = False
            self.falling = True

        self.update_pos()

    def fall(self):
        if self.y_pos < FLOOR:
            self.x_pos += 1*self.direction
            self.y_pos += 5
        else:
            self.falling = False

        self.update_pos()

    def InvisWalls(self):
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.direction = -self.direction
        if self.rect.right > screen.get_width():
            self.direction = -self.direction

        self.update_pos()

    def update_pos(self):
        self.rect.x = self.x_pos
        self.rect.y = self.y_pos

FLOOR = 700
CEILING = 10

my_ball = Attacker('wackyball.bmp',[300, FLOOR])
delay = 100
interval = 50
pygame.key.set_repeat(delay, interval)



running = True
while running:
    if my_ball.jumping:
        my_ball.jump()
    if my_ball.falling:
        my_ball.fall()
    else:
        my_ball.InvisWalls()

    screen.blit(my_ball.image, my_ball.rect)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                my_ball.y_pos -= 25
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                my_ball.y_pos += 25
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                my_ball.direction = 1
                my_ball.x_pos += 25
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                my_ball.direction = -1
                my_ball.x_pos -= 25
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if not my_ball.falling:
                    my_ball.jumping = True
                my_ball.update_pos()
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(my_ball.image, my_ball.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

My problem is that when my ball jumps, it goes up in a straight line and goes down in a straight line as well. My attempts of making the ball jump in a curved line has only failed and only made the jump faster. How can I make the ball go up and down in a continuous curved line like how a real ball does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue when I made a basic platform game.  I solved it by having a vertical velocity variable (zero when not jumping).  When the player jumped I set the velocity to a maximum and then decremented it with every refresh of the screen (when it gets below zero it then starts falling).  When I detected that the player had landed I then set it back to zero.

NOTE: if you want you can set a maximum downward velocity check, to simulate the "terminal velocity" of the object.  If you want some really cool stuff you can also look into 'gravity well' style designs, but that's a bit more advanced.

Comment: Can you show me some code I can add/fix to my current piece of code?

Comment: Unfortunately I made the game a long time ago and the source files have since been lost/corrupted.  From memory When jump was pressed I set the upward velocity to the max value and set a FALLING var to TRUE.  Then each loop I decrement the velocity and move the player that many pixels and then check for collisions (move player back up until no more collisions).  Once it has landed FALLIING = FALSE.  It shouldn't be too tough.  You can also find some good "How to make a platformer" tutorials on youtube if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your ball moves in a straight line because it has a constant `y` velocity. To make it curve the way a real ball does, you need to incorporate some physics into your model. That is, change the `y`-velocity based on the ball's acceleration due to gravity. The necessary equation is: v_y = v_y(0) - gt where v_y(0) is the initial y-velocity at time t=0 and g is the acceleration due to gravity (10 m.s^-2 on Earth).

Without making big changes to your code, look to alter the lines `self.y_pos += 5` and `self.y_pos -= 5` so that instead of the  constant ±5, you add smaller and smaller numbers to the y-position on the way up and subtract larger and larger numbers on the way down.

Comment: Can you add some code so I can apply it into my code?